# How do I ask for an input within an IF statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

I'm a beginner so sorry if my code looks messy. I'm trying to make a code that asks if you want to count the Perimeter OR the Area of a Triangle OR a Square, just can't figure out the best way to attach q1 and q2.

Preferably the code would print the chosen way of calculating and also would change the "x" variable to 1 if you have chosen the Area of a Square or change it to 2 if you have chosen the Perimeter of a Square etc.

Feel free to give any coding tips.

```
q1 = input("Type 1 for Square, type 2 for Triangle."))

if q1 == "1":
    q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter."))
      if q2 == "1":
        print("Calculating the Area of a Square.")
        x = 1
      else:
        print("Calculating the Perimeter of a Square.")
        x = 2

else:
    q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter."))
      if q2 == "1":
        print("Calculating the Area of a Triangle.")
        x = 3
      else:
        print("Calculating the Perimeter of a Triangle.")
        x = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all branches from the conditionals are going to ask both questions, I would simply ask both first then test both result at the same time:

```
q1 = input("Type 1 for Square, type 2 for Triangle.")
q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter.")

if q1 == "1" and q2 == "1":
    # Area of a Square
    print(...)
    x = 1
elif q1 == "1" and q2 == "2":
    # Perimeter of a Square
    print(...)
    x = 2
elif q1 == "2" and q2 == "1":
    # Area of a Triangle
    print(...)
    x = 3
elif q1 == "2" and q2 == "2":
    # Perimeter of a Triangle
    print(...)
    x = 4
else:
    # The not valid input cases (never forget about non nominal cases)
    raise ValueError('Not valid input q1 {} q2 {}'.format(q1, q2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more clean ways to do what you are trying to do, but I found this approach beginner friendly, simply ask the user to input for both question on the start of the program and since there are only 4 options - check all of them.

```
q1 = input("Type 1 for Square, type 2 for Triangle.")
q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter.")


if q1 == "1" and q2 == "1":
    #do something
    
if q1 == "1" and q2 == "2":
    #do something
    
if q1 == "2" and q2 == "1":
    #do something
    
if q1 == "2" and q2 == "2":
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

several things to make this code more efficient!

```
q1 = input("Type 1 for Square, type 2 for Triangle."))
```

you might want to add this line over here too:`q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter."))`
Now you should assign this variable here

```
x = q2
```

and then make the proper adjustments.
final code:

```
q1 = input("Square or triangle? type 1 for square type 2 for triangle")
q2 = input("Type 1 for Area, Type 2 for Perimeter."))
x = q2
if q1 == "1":
   if x == "1":
        print("Calculating the Area of a Square.")
      else:
        print("Calculating the Perimeter of a Square.")
else:
   if x == "1":
      print("Calculating the Area of a Triangle.")
      
   else:
      print("Calculating the Perimeter of a Triangle.")
```

if it doesn't work let me know, I'll try and fix it!